# MySQL & PHP Performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, mysqli

I have a question regarding the differences between mysql_query (which I know is being deprecated and will soon be obsolete) and mysqli and the relative performance difference that I notice.

So putting this as simply as I can - I developed an API from scratch in PHP 5.4, I am using MySQL v5.0.96, running on a LAMP server (centos, apache, mysql, php) with quad core 3.0GHz, 16GB ram, 100mbps duplex con... A standard server really.

To make the initial call to the API from POSTMAN (great app if you don't know it - it's a google chrome extension worth a look) will take an average of 160ms, which considering that I am on the other side of the world, and have to do some authentication checks, I am not too fussed about the rest but what really stunned me was the difference in performance between the two sets of code below:

The call + the return of an array of 55 results in my indexed table using mysqli as below:

```
    $mysqli = new \mysqli("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "database", 3306);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, name FROM products ORDER BY id");
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
```

The mysqli above takes an average of 850ms, with some spikes at 1000ms and some lows of 650ms

In comparison, which I just did because I thought it seemed incredibly high for returning an array of 55 records, I decided to use the old fashioned mysql_query (which yes I know - is obsolete etc...) with the following code, which as you'll notice I've been careful to replicate both as identically as I can just using the different method.

```
    $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","username","password");
    if (!$con){ die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
    mysql_select_db('database', $con);
    $row = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM products ORDER BY id");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row[] = $rows;
    }
    return $row;
```

The mysql_query took an average of 220ms with some highs of 300ms and some lows of 180ms

Can anyone out there point me out why the original mysql_query is four times faster than the new mysqli?? I can't get my head around why that would happen... I'd be keen to know if I am doing something wrong with mysqli or just a weird observation? Surely newer would normally mean better, and hence better would mean faster / more accurate for less computational power required?

Comment: Have a look at XDebug and profiling (http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to check what actually takes time.

Comment: Better !== Faster.... Speed isn't the only possible improvement; the ability to use prepared statements/bind variables is a major improvement, which makes MySQLi a great deal better than its predecessor... this has both positive benefits for both performance and security

Comment: @MarkBaker the difference is too high to give out a sermon like this. there is an obvious *technical* reason somewhere for the *particular* mysqli instance to perform so slow. While of course usually mysqli performs not as bad as to be defended such way

Comment: HI @ hank I will have a look at that - thank you! @ MarkBaker - oh don't get me wrong - I love some of the new features, yes better is not ALWAYS faster, and have been using mysqli for the past 3 or so years (spent a while with PDO before that but I didn't like it much). First time I deal with 10,000+ records and getting frequent timeouts... @YourCommonSense - I think you've hit the nail on the head there, that is why I thought I'd put the question out there - maybe someone has a clear cut answer, or maybe I am just doing something wrong? The SQL is really simple though...

Comment: did you clear the mysql cache between the tests?

Comment: Yes, at glance your mysqli code is all right. So, the problem is somewhere deeper.BTW, you don't need no fancy debuggers to measure. just add `microtime(1)` calls around connect, query execution and fetch loop. and post the timings.

Comment: Can you try setting MYSQLI_USE_RESULT as a second parameter in query.  It might be because the default value MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT will fetch the whole result set. This makes subsequent calls faster but it might account for the mysqli->query delay.

Comment: @ Gerald Schneider - I've disabled all the cache that I had setup as I thought initially it may have been the caching causing a problem. @YourCommonSense I have run those - and it is quite extraordinary! The average (ran 50times each) for mysql_query was: 0.00080599 - and mysqli was: 0.00934625= (to 5 S.F) there is a 10 fold difference. Staggering! (I got those by subtracting the start value from the end value) Can anyone else reproduce these results? I am a little baffled!!

Comment: by the way, you can address only one person with @ and you have to make it close to the name. so, better write distinct comments for everyone

Comment: @DobromirVelev just about to go out for lunch - feel famished... But I shall give that a go when I get back, and let you know if it changes anything! Thanks to everyone!

Comment: @YourCommonSense I keep forgetting that it isn't like facebook - will do in future - thanks!

Comment: I'd like to ask you also to run phpinfo() on that host and tell us what does it say under "Client API version" param in  mysql and mysqli sections.

Comment: I just ran a similar test on my local test rig but the results are pretty consistent and there is no significant difference in query performance either way. I guess there is something else causing this - check the mysql/i configs in php.ini, check if the server is loaded or if some table locking is happening at the time.

Comment: @user3415605 do you still experience this problem? Are you interested in it anymore? Would you like me to put a bounty for a question?

Answer (score -2):

mysql_query, the traditional way has its own advantage due to its simplicity.
Where as mysqli has its own.

It depends on the mysql database how it is designed, and accordingly speed depends on it.

If you need to connect to your database more than once or again and again, its better to use mysqli as it will not make multi-connections to your database from a single host, whereas mysql_query the traditional way, will make multiple connections, this could reach the maximum number of connection limit of the database host. But yes more the connections, faster the work.

Comment: I wonder if it was produced by some sort of random text generator.

Comment: Its with experience. I am just sharing my experience. When I use mysql_query then I get error from host "you have reached maximum number of mysql connections", but when I use mysqli, I don't get any such error (in the same code).

Comment: That's very funny experience :)